# How to reliably lay out continuous unfolded diagrams of 3D shapes

Tags: geometry

This is a bit of an interdisciplinary question, but I suppose here is the best place to put it.

I am designing a 3D printed plastic toy with LEDs and knobs in Blender using Python. The LEDs are soldered to a long strip of flexible circuit board, which is weaved through the plastic structure.

[image: Flexible circuit board folded onto the 3D]

The 3D shape in question is produced as follows. Take a unit 4D cube, and on all 8 of its faces, place the following 3D object: a 3x3x3 grid of rhombicuboctahedra, joined by square prisms. Project this 4D object to 3D using fisheye projection.

[image: Compound 3D shape]

But for simplicity, let's focus only on one of the faces, ideally one of the more distorted ones. The model can be downloaded here: [STL File](https://git.mckay-bednar.net/jiri/mc4d-hw/src/branch/master/teseract-side-basic.stl).

Now, I want an LED on every triangle face of every rhombicuboctahedron of that face, all of them connected with a single strip of flexible circuit board.

## Constraints

1. The circuit board must touch the 3D surface
2. the circuit board may not intersect itself when spread flat
   [image: Self-intersection on flat surface]
3. The circuit may not cross itself once folded onto the 3D body
4. The strip may not go over the thin faces of the distorted prism.
   [image: Bridge]

My question is, how to reliably and efficiently design the shape of the flexible circuit board? I can usually get about 12 rhombicuboctahedra covered, but then as they become used up and the path within the grid becomes more and more constrained, I struggle to not run into the self-intersection problem.

Comment: So your goal is to touch each triangular face of each rhombicuboctahedron according to those constraints? Must the piece of flexible circuit board be a single strip, or could it possibly branch out?

Comment: Correct. And it may not branch within a single face (face is one whole 3x3x3 grid). However, if you find a solution that uses 2 or 3 separate stripes, each terminating at some accessible spot, I'd accept that too.

Comment: Hm. This is a tricky problem, even with an undistorted grid graph. I suggest trying to build your path from predesigned modules, composing pieces like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpPwn.png) whose ends point just about straight away from one another.

Comment: @Magma is right when he says this is a tricky problem. I think the general astract folding problem this is an instance of is unsolved. You should try for an engineering compromise.

Comment: If you don't know about this 4d Rubik's cube website you probably should: http://superliminal.com/cube/cube.htm

Comment: I am actually one of the solvers of the 5x5x5x5 (currently attempting the 3x3x3x3x3). That's what prompted this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky problem, even with an undistorted grid graph. If you want to find a path manually, I suggest trying to build your path from predesigned modules, composing pieces whose ends point just about straight away from one another, like this one:

[image]

Alternatively, if you have the programming skills, you could try letting a computer program do the trial and error for you, generating a bunch of random layouts until it finds one that does not self-intersect.

Comment: If I create a pattern where the ends go "straight away from one another", my net ends up looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiiJD.png

Comment: By "straight away" I mean in UV coordinates, not in 3D space. Note that my pattern doesn't start and end on opposite prisms.

Comment: In that case I agree, but I'll need to build a library of "turns" to give me a better maneuverability within the cube.

Comment: After considering multiple separate strips and trying some configurations, I found one that can connect a 1*2*3 block: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWPKW.jpg. I will just repeat this 4 times, and then do a half version for the center 1*1*3 column.